# python - count AABB-like occurrence in a list

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a list as below:

```
a=[0,0,2,4,4,6,6,9,12,13,13,16,16,21,21,24,26,26,28,28,31,34,34,37,37]
```

The list satisfies:

1.sorted in ascending order

2.each number occurs 1-2 times

How to count all AABB-like occurrence in the list?

In the above example the answer should be `5`

(4,4,6,6) (13,13,16,16) (16,16,21,21) (26,26,28,28) (34,34,37,37)

Comment: You could start with writing some code ;)

Comment: @Loser For `0,0` it would have to be `0,0,2,2` but it is `0,0,2,4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. The simplest I could think of is using 'enumerate' and list comprehension with a condition to test for 'aabb' patterns.

```
result = len([x for idx,x in enumerate(a) if idx<len(a)-3 and x == a[idx+1] and x!=a[idx+2] and a[idx+2] == a[idx+3]])
```

The idx < len(a) - 3 avoids index problems.

Answer (score 1):

Although it may not seem that way at first (because you are processing a list of ints) this is actually an example of a [string searching algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm).

If you look at the wikipedia article (linked to above) you will see that there are quite a few uses for such algorithms, beyond simply searching strings, one major one being searching DNA sequences for a given pattern, so it is quite an important area of computer science.

As well as multiple uses there are multiple implementations so you could approach this several ways.

The naive approach is to simple iterate through the list and check to see if the next element matches the current element and then if the following elements also match. The problem here is that you have to go through the whole list and then iterate through each sublist to check if it matches the given pattern. In big O notation we say this approach has a complexity of `O(nm)` where n is the length of the list and m is the length of the pattern you are searching, so it is not very efficient.

There are many ways to improve on the naive approach, and there may even be some that are unknown. I'll leave that to you to figure out, but hope this gives you some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through - and compare the pairs

```
a=[0,0,2,4,4,6,6,9,12,13,13,16,16,21,21,24,26,26,28,28,31,34,34,37,37]
for i in range(len(a)-3):
  if (a[i]==a[i+1] and a[i+2]==a[i+3]):
    print(str(a[i])+str(a[i+1])+str(a[i+2])+str(a[i+3]))
```